# Can't Understand Sha256 In Blockchaining

Tags: algorithm, function, blockchain, sha256

I understand the sha256 function takes a string input and produces a hexadecimal output. I am unsure how the input is used exactly. So in a block in a block chain I am assuming the it uses the parent hash, the data and nonce as input. I think the parent hash and the data are maybe concatenated together and the nonce is used in the function somewhere else. Or maybe the nonce is the number of times the sha256 function is run to have the block solved with the previous output hash as the new input? Can someone please explain this properly to me as I have yet to find an answer yet?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#Mining

Answer (score 2):

In Bitcoin, the following data is serialized (into one 80 byte value), then hashed twice using SHA256 to produce the [Block Hash](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm):

- Version (4 bytes)
- Previous Block Hash (32 bytes)
- Merkle Root Hash (32 bytes)
- Timestamp (4 bytes)
- nBits (4 bytes)
- nonce (4 bytes)

The [merkle root](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Merkle_Trees) is the root of a merkle tree of all the transactions in the block, the [nBits](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#target-nbits) describe the difficulty target that the block hash must meet in order to be considered valid, and the nonce may be changed by the miner each time the hashing function is done until a valid block hash is found.

### Example

Grab a block (eg. block 3): [Block 3 in json](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000082b5015589a3fdf2d4baff403e6f0be035a5d9742c1cae6295464449?format=json) or [Block 3 in hex](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000082b5015589a3fdf2d4baff403e6f0be035a5d9742c1cae6295464449?format=hex)

Concatenate (in this order, little endian, hex format) the version, previous block hash, merkle root, unix epoch time, difficulty target (bits), and nonce. You’ll see you can copy the first 160 characters from the [Block 3 in hex link](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000082b5015589a3fdf2d4baff403e6f0be035a5d9742c1cae6295464449?format=hex).

`01000000bddd99ccfda39da1b108ce1a5d70038d0a967bacb68b6b63065f626a0000000044f672226090d85db9a9f2fbfe5f0f9609b387af7be5b7fbb7a1767c831c9e995dbe6649ffff001d05e0ed6d`

Run the command:

```
echo 01000000bddd99ccfda39da1b108ce1a5d70038d0a967bacb68b6b63065f626a0000000044f672226090d85db9a9f2fbfe5f0f9609b387af7be5b7fbb7a1767c831c9e995dbe6649ffff001d05e0ed6d | xxd -r -p | openssl sha -sha256 | xxd -r -p | openssl sha -sha256

Reverse the output from
```

`4944469562ae1c2c74d9a535e00b6f3e40ffbad4f2fda3895501b58200000000`

to

`0000000082b5015589a3fdf2d4baff403e6f0be035a5d9742c1cae6295464449`

And there’s the block hash!